# rosjava network setup

Tags: ros, rosjava, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running roscore on a remote computer.

I created a modified RosRunClass to manually set master URI.

```
    final String master = argv[argv.length - 1]; // http://10.159.1.24:11311
    nodeConfiguration.setMasterUri(new URI(master));
```

I've also overridden Advertise URI as follows:

```
    AdvertiseAddressFactory adress = new AdvertiseAddressFactory() {
        String _master = master;
        @Override
        public AdvertiseAddress newDefault() {
            String IPADDRESS_PATTERN = "(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)";
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(IPADDRESS_PATTERN);
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(_master);
            if (matcher.find()) _master = matcher.group();
            else _master = "localhost";
            return new AdvertiseAddress(_master);
        }
    };
    
    nodeConfiguration.setXmlRpcAdvertiseAddressFactory(adress);
    nodeConfiguration.setTcpRosAdvertiseAddressFactory(adress);
```

However I still get following exception when I try to register a new Publisher.

org.ros.exception.RosRuntimeException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in authority at index 7: http://10.159.1.24 192.168.56.1:60076/

I have no idea where "192.168.56.1" comes from as this is NOT my internal (nor external) IP.

I'm using newest rosjava available in Ubuntu repositories (for ros indigo).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216004/rosjava-network-setup/) by [smihael](https://answers.ros.org/users/23102/smihael/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2015-08-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found out what my problem was. Despite $ROS_MASTER_IP being set correctly, $ROS_IP was not set in bash session from where I launched my node.

---

Originally posted by [smihael](https://answers.ros.org/users/23102/smihael/) with karma: 45 on 2015-08-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0